# Reading dates from Sqlite with Delphi / Firedac

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

When reading date fields from Sqlite into Firedac, I get conversion errors. The fields are called dates but with string entries (yyyy-mm-dd). I set the option for Datetime Format = string, but I've discovered that while null values are handled OK, empty values (= '') produce an error which I can't figure out how to handle.

Comment: Can you post some code?  Sqllite stores dates as strings or integers, so you'll probably need to do some conversion. If we see some code, perhaps we can help..

Comment: Well, empty strings are not valid date strings. What should happen with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [**StrsEmpty2Null**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFormatOptions.StrsEmpty2Null) option, which will automatically convert all empty strings to NULL state. But it's for all values and parameters handled by the data component. So it's not the cure.

I'm not sure what you're doing, but in general, NULL is a state and you cannot convert NULL state to a value because it's a state indicating no value. So as you cannot convert empty string to date.

So try to describe more about your value to string conversion, so we can suggest a proper way to deal with it. For SQLite, I'd suggest using [**DATE**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types) pseudo data type and convert values through the built-in formatting expressions.

Comment: Thanks. The StrsEmpty2Null option fixed the problem. I'm creating an app that can list tables and fields from any Sqlite database and execute queries. Firedac's inability to handle empty strings in date fields was hanging me up. Certainly, for a targeted DB app, the DB should not have a mix of null and empty strings.

Comment: You're welcome! But well, for tool like you describe is no good to enable `StrsEmpty2Null` option (because it will NULL all empty string values, and parameter values). What if me, as a user of such application want to see which values are empty and which are NULL? Let's find a better way. Could you please elaborate how do you work with the dataset component? Do you build persistent fields? Or what and when raises exception or causes some issue?

Comment: StrsEmpty2Null does display empties and nulls the same, but I can still query for empty (x = '') or null (x = null) separately. However, it doesn't help with crappy data like date = '2009-02-29'.

Comment: I thought I could handle that with an option for data mapping, but when I tried a map rule setting on my query object (dtDate to dtAnsiString), I got an error that max length was zero (even though I set sizemax. I don't use persistent fields because the purpose of this project is to open any sqlite db and query it.

Comment: Well, I have still not enough information to help. Do you identify the data type by yourself? If so, consider how to handle a table with a single tuple with text value `2017-09-26`. Will you treat that as date field? Is the date format constant (by SQLite supported ISO definition)? Then, what if someone adds another tuple with text `ABCD`? This topic is quite wide. Maybe try asking another question and desribe how do you _detect_ field types for date, time and date-time data types for non FireDAC databases in detail.

Comment: It's really a conflict between Sqlite's 'advisory' typing and FireDAC's strict typing. And it's stricter for dates than numbers. One option would be display everything as text, but I can't figure out how to do that with mapping.

Comment: Well, there's a limited set of data types in SQLite as we both know. My point is, how do you want to detect date field defined by non FireDAC application? Or what do you mean by _"advisory"_ typing? I wish I could help but I still don't know how do you map data types from any SQLite database to FireDAC.

Comment: I'm going to start with a new question.